# X86 assembly: Why a basic block has cmp and test instructions, seems duplicate of work

Tags: assembly, x86, g++

Here is my c function:

```
bool equalA = true;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    
    if (str[i] != 'a') {
        equalA = false; 
    }
}
if (equalA == true) {
    if(str.compare(4, 6, "matches")) {
        printf("%s", "matches\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the patial assembly code:

```
movzbl  (%rax), %eax
cmpb    $97, %al
setne   %al
testb   %al, %al
je  .L5
movb    $0, -981(%rbp)
.L5:
addl    $1, -980(%rbp)
jmp .L6
```

The code above checks str[i] with 'a', if not equal, movb set equalA to false. If equal, jump to .L5. and continue for loop.

My question is:
Shouldn't

```
  cmpb  $97, %al
  je .L5
```

would do the same work?

if str[i] == 'a', zflag will be set, je .L5 would take the branch.
if str[i] ！= 'a', zflag will be cleared. je .L5 would not take the branch.

Why Compiler generates two lines of extra code after cmpb instruction?

Comment: Without optimization, it makes sense that the compiler interpreted the code very literally: make a flag, then test that flag. That's what you wrote, so that is what happened, because optimizations were off.

Comment: You told the compiler not to optimize, so it didn't.  It happened to choose to materialize the `bool` result of the comparison into a register and then test it.  It already had to store it to memory because of `-O0`.

Comment: @syacer please [don’t assume you know who voted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post); you asked why the post got a downvote and someone tried to give you feedback. Don’t correlate the two. Voting is a normal action on this site, so not take it personally.

Comment: @syaet: please read our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), and leave handling behaviour to us moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it should do the same.  I assume you did not compile with optimizations enabled.  It is hard to explain why a C compiler generated certain code.  A different compiler, btw, may have generated different code.  Yet another might generate this code, despite optimizations being enabled.

However, this is an extreme oversimplification, see the excellent comment by @PeterCordes below for more details about a program's optimization.

Comment: Yes, without optimization.

Comment: Enable optimizations, and very likely those extra lines will go away.  The code generators of most C/C++ compilers generate some kind of "template code" with room for optimization that is left to a latter optimization phase that can handle such redudancies more easily and across multiple such "templates".

Comment: @Tom: That's an over-simplified description to the point of being inaccurate.  Optimizations like this mostly happen on an internal representation of the program logic, usually an [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form.  For GCC, it's GIMPLE (SSA), then RTL for register allocation and stuff, then finally generating asm.  So it's not like it turns your source into x86 asm templates and *then* optimizes those; it optimizes before generating asm when the program logic is in a state with fewer machine-specific and register allocation details nailed down.